# Highcharts php data

Tags: php, highcharts

I don`t know how I can display data in loop with highcharts:

```
data: [<?php for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { ?>
                            [ <?php echo $dane[$i];
                            echo ",";
                            $i++;
                            echo $dane[$i];?>  ] 
                            <?php } ?>
                        ]
```

and this display nothing.
But when i try:

```
data: [[ <?php 
           echo $dane[$i];
           echo ",";
           $i++;
           echo $dane[$i]; 
          ?>
           ]]
```

Display good, but only for one data.

Answer (score 0):

$i++ is not necessary inside of FOR loop because you define increment/decrement in last parameter in FOR  syntax.
for ($i=0; $i < 10; **$i++**)

from your code ... try this ....

```
echo 'data: [';
    for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        echo '[' . $dane[$i] . "," . $dane[($i+1)] . ']';
    }
echo ']' ;
```

if is json, you can try [JSON encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) it might be usefull for you

Answer (score 0):

You can run loop, prepare output array in php and then print in data only this returned array. Optionally you can also use json_encode();

Comment: I prepare output array, that I have: Array ( [0] => 1174 [1] => , [2] => 24 [3] => 2286 [4] => , [5] => 40 [6], but when I try print_r($dane) it`s display blank page. I also tray with Array ( [0] => [ [1] => 985 [2] => , [3] => 7 [4] => ] [5] => [ [6] => 2529 [7] => , [8] => 32 [9] => ] and data: [<?php  print_r($dane);
?>] but it`s steel blank page.

Comment: I advice to take look at the artciel about preprocessing http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing